# How to find word matches using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to match word from a content and if word is matched then i want to show other content.

```js
var match = 'song.mp3';

if(  // in match find .mp3 ) {
  
  $('.show').text('true');
  
  } else {
  
  $('.show').text('error');
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain bit what u exactly wants? U want to match the `.mp3` formate at the last of the string

Comment: Start [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: `if(match.match(/\.mp3/))` ?

Comment: Yes if word find `.mp3` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply try this

```
if(match.match(/\.mp3/))
```

or

```
var match = 'song.mp3';
var newString = match.split('.');
if(newString === 'mp3'){
....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An example of checking text inside string is

```js
str =  "abc.mp3";
var n = str.search(".mp3");
if(n > -1)
document.write('found');
else
document.write('not found');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = 'song.mp3';
var abc = 'mp3'
if(abc.test(match))
{
   $('.show').text('true');
} 
else {
   $('.show').text('error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var match = 'song.mp3';

    if (match.indexOf('mp3') > -1)
    {
        $('.show').text('true');

    } 
   else
    {

      $('.show').text('error');

    }
```